# Why is Integer.MIN_VALUE seen as a double by nashorn?

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I pass Integer.MIN_VALUE in some Javascript that just returns the input. However, it seems that when I compare the result of the Javascript by using `ScriptValueConverter.unwrapValue(returnedObject)`, the value is the same but the type is a double while I am expecting an integer.

However when I pass Integer.MAX_VALUE in, I do get an integer.

From what I understand, Nashorn uses optimistic type casting so in my eyes, MIN_VALUE can still be an int, there's no need for it to be a double

Comment: But Nashorn is not required to return an `Integer`. Perhaps it stores value and sign separately at one point, thus, can’t represent `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as `int` there, perhaps that changes with the next update, who knows?

Comment: Perhaps a typo, you meant Integer.MIN_VALUE instead?
I know it isn't required to return an integer but it's a bit unusual isn't it, if Nashorn uses optimistic type casting, MIN_VALUE obviously can be represent as an int still but Nashorn chooses to use double, which is not consistent with how it treats MAX_VALUE

Comment: Yes, I meant, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` can’t be represented as “`int` magnitude and sign”. Sometimes, code trying to handle both cases has such issues. The non-intuitive solution would be be to represent the value as “negation of magnitude and sign” during processing. Not everyone does this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem is not Nashorn itself but the javascript code you are running or the third party converter you are using (`ScriptValueConverter` is neither a `javax.script` nor a `jdk.nashorn` class).

I've run the following code:

```
    ScriptEngine jsEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    jsEngine.eval("function identity(x) {return x;}");
    System.out.println("Integer.MIN_VALUE:" + ((Invocable) jsEngine).invokeFunction("identity", Integer.MIN_VALUE).getClass());
    System.out.println("Integer.MAX_VALUE:" +((Invocable) jsEngine).invokeFunction("identity", Integer.MAX_VALUE).getClass());
```

and the output is:

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE: class java.lang.Integer
Integer.MAX_VALUE: class java.lang.Integer
```

Here you can find a brief explanation about [nashorn type conversions](http://www.n-k.de/riding-the-nashorn/#_nashorn_type_conversions).